# Ubuntu Virtual Server JeOS - Server app recomendations

Tags: web-server, java, ubuntu, ftp

I wanted to start experimenting with ubuntu server.  I installed a minimal virtual machine from ubuntu server 64bit 9.04 on my mac running 10.6.1 with WMware Fusion.  It is command line only.

Here are the things I managed to get accomplished:

Install VMwareTools,
install ssh,
set a static ip,
mount and link a shared directory with my mac,
enable read/write permissions in shared directory from both machines.

I'm not looking for guides on how to do the installs, I can do that research myself.  I'm looking for some recommendations on apps that accomplish the things I would like to do with the server.

I'm looking to host a web server, ftp server, stream media, file share.  I'd also like to install popular web technologies such as java, php, phython, mysql.

Any recommendations/advice for first install, first time using a cmd line only os user...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a webserver you probably want apache2. It's not the simplest, but it is the standard. For ftpd, you want one of either vsftpd, or proftpd. Pick one, they're similarly useful, and there doesn't seem to be a consensus on which to use. Samba's probably the best way for file sharing, unless you're sharing to only *nix hosts, in which case I'd just use NFS. The install for all of these can be done from apt. `apt-cache search <whatever>` to find the package name, and then `apt-get install <package name>` to actually install it.